# Changing dist directory in Nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I'm building an API based on Nestjs. The `main.ts` file is nested in a subfolder of my `src` directory. As a result, the compiled files are also nested in the `dist` directory and my entry point is `dist/api/main.js` instead of `dist/main.js`. I would like to keep things that way.

When starting my app with `npm run start:dev`, I get the following error:

```
4:47:32 PM - Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/ymonb/Nest.js/myProject/dist/main'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:17)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:859:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I need to be able to reconfigure Nest with the new path. I looked into [the documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/usages#nest-start), but I don't see anything to specify a different entry point.

I think that maybe I need to edit `nest-cli.json`, but I can't find any documentation about the possible options in this file (if you know of such documentation, i'm interested!).

This is my `nest-cli.json`:

```
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src/api"
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 24):

You can edit nest-cli.json like this:

```
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "entryFile": "your/main/js/path"
}
```

and nest-cli will load: `your/main/js/path.js`

I found config in source code. [nest-cli/lib/configuration/configuration.ts](https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/blob/master/lib/configuration/configuration.ts)

Answer (score 5):

Go to your "nest-cli.json" and edit the "entryFile" config. 
It should be linked to the main.js file inside the "dist/main" file. 
It should look like this :

```js
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "entryFile": "copy the relative path of your main.js and paste it here"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are typescript build configurations.
Change `rootDir` entry in `tsconfig.json` file to `src`.
Doing that will replicate the structure under src to dist.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it didn't work. I'm not sure that it is related to Typescript, because the compilation works fine. In fact, `npm run build` runs perfectly. The problem seems to be that Nest doesn't find the files in the dist directory. This is why I think the Nest configuration is wrong, and not Typescript. I have put some code on [Github](https://github.com/hrsr1291/temporaryNestProject) to reproduce the issue. Just `npm install` and `npm run start:dev`.

Comment: Make sure that `outDir` in `tsconfig.json` points to `dist` and not to `dist/api` and in nest-cli.json change `"sourceRoot": "src/api"` to `"sourceRoot": "src"`. Try these.