# specify entry for standard nestjs project?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

referencing codes that are placed out of the project makes a difference in the dist folder structure and nest cannot found an entry.

let's say I have a project like this

```
folder
- nestjs-project
- - dist
- - src
- - - app.module.ts
- - tsconfig.json

- common
- - interfaces
- - - index.ts
```

and when I compile a project, it will produce a build with this dist structure.

```
dist
├── nestjs-project
│   └── src
│       ├── main.js
├── common
│   └── interfaces
│       ├── index.js
└── tsconfig.build.tsbuildinfo
```

the code structure should be like this to work

```
dist
└── src
     ├── main.js
```

(entry should be `dist/src/main.js`, not `dist/nestjs-project/src/main.js`)

when I start dev server, nest trying to find an entry file in the wrong folder, and throw this error.
`Error: Cannot find module '/workspaces/github-badge-project/API/dist/main'`

I did some search and I found that with nest-cli.json config, I can manually **set `the source folder`** and **`entry path`** if the mode is `monorepo` (https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo)
but I couldn't find how to set the entry for the `standard project`, how I fix this issue?

Comment: Answered via https://stackoverflow.com/q/59601630/901597 ?